# PCB Size and Placement Issue

Tags: pcb, pcb-design

I have completed my schematic design and started PCB layout. I am considering two layers and 45 mm x 95 mm. There are not any critical signals and according to current values of nets, I will draw power nets with 40 mils and 12 mils for others.

My desired board size is indicated at the bottom-left side of the image below. Do you think that this size is enough for these components? Thank you for sharing your ideas. I am trying to put it as at most 2 layers because of the cost of 4 layers is much higher than relative 2 layer board.

This is the layout;

[image]

Comment: What's the total area of all of the components (their outline)? What is the area of the PCB? A rule of thumb would be that PCB size is total components area + 20-30% to have a not-that-dense layout.

Comment: I am using Altium Designer 16. Do you know a way that i can measure the total size of components? I am intending to make 45mmx95mm for PCB as the arrow indicates on image. If you are asking the all black area's size, that is 610mmx305mm.

Comment: I can tell you how we were doing it once. We have taken the physical components and measured them with a caliper :)

Comment: On a 2-layer board you will want to allow more than 30% extra area beyond what the components themselves fill. Also, 12 mil tracks are very wide for signals. Most fabs have no issue with 4 mil nowadays. Maybe use 6 mil if you want to really good yield.

Comment: Also, what size components are you using? If that long edge is 100 mm, I guess you must be using 0805 and larger parts. Smaller sizes will really hep you meet your size target.

Comment: You don't indicate that the pcb size must remain at 45x95.  Maybe you don't need to stress over this limitation yet.  Start grouping components, and placing them in sections (based off your schematic).  Then start squeezing the groups together to get a better idea of how much room they will take up.  Can you place on both sides of the PCB?  It's sometimes amazing how well the components compact.  It's sometimes infuriating how much they don't.  Good luck.

Comment: Thank you. I am using 805 package. I will use top and bottom but i have some doubts about routing part. Worst case i can increase the size but if it can be like this, it is more preferable. I think it can possible, what do you think? Maybe some zero ohms' implementation if the plug in or out is necessary, however it seems possible for me.

Comment: @layout789 well, we can't tell you from looking at this whether *we* would manage to do that, and we have no idea how good *you* are at compact layouting, so, how *on earth* should we assess this? You can get either a "yes" or a "no", but neither answer would help you in any way.-

Comment: So, since an answer wouldn't be unambiguous without a mathematical proof of impossibility or with a practical proof of possibility by routing, I'd say your question is unclear **or** impossible to answer. VTC.

Comment: I was not asking a proof. I just want to discuss your senses related experiences.

Comment: ^ All of the above will also depend on your tolerance for vias. With a dense two-layer board and surface-mount parts, prepare for lots and lots of trace vias.

Comment: Is this a hobby project or a production run?

Comment: Choose the box first. You kinda need to do it all at the same time - design the circuit, layout the board, choose the box. You'll also want to check where the connections go tom what type they are and how they're mounted. _Whatever you do - don't have the board made before the box is selected._

Answer (score 2):

The first thing would be to add up all of the areas (or group them in altium) and see what area they take up, your board needs to be bigger than this area.

You also need to account for via's and traces, I'd add 20% to 40% of the component area but this is what I do, and is design dependent. Remember that the time it takes you to route is also a cost, and on low quantity boards it might not save you any money to make the board smaller.

The last thing would be to remember that if you want a silkscreen with printed reference designators, this will take some additional room (although not much because you can print this over traces.)

Comment: Thank you. I will drop some components from schematic and also increase the board size.